# Regex to drop character before a character set

Tags: python, regex

I need convert pandas dataframe.

I have dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['10SGD01|AA169|10SGD01|AA170']})
```

I need to get:

```
data
10SGD01AA169|10SGD01AA170
```

I use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace('|(?=AA)', '', regex=True)
```

This regex does not work. Where is the mistake?
Version of pandas == 2.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need escape `|` because special regex character:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'\|(?=AA)', '', regex=True)
print (df)
                        data
0  10SGD01AA169|10SGD01AA170
```